# Can i make symbols draggable with JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

What i want to do is create this chess like "game". You should be able to drag the symbols freely around, kinda like the chess helpers you can find online. Simple really.

But my problem is to move the symbols, is anyone able to help?

```
    `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        html, body {
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
        }

        .black {
            background-color:silver;

        }

        table {
            margin:auto;
            text-align:center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
    <body>
        <table border="1" style="border:1px black solid;">
            <tr>
                <td width="40px" height="40px">&#9820;</td>
                <td class="black" width="40px" height="40px">&#9822;</td>
                <td width="40px" height="40px">&#9821;</td>
                <td class="black" width="40px" height="40px">&#9819;</td>
                <td width="40px" height="40px">&#9818;</td>
                <td class="black" width="40px" height="40px">&#9821;</td>
                <td width="40px" height="40px">&#9822;</td>
                <td class="black" width="40px" height="40px">&#9820;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="black" width="40px" height="40px">&#9823;</td>
                <td width="40px" height="40px">&#9823;</td>
                <td class="black" width="40px" height="40px">&#9823;</td>
                <td width="40px" height="40px">&#9823;</td>
                <td class="black" width="40px" height="40px">&#9823;</td>
                <td width="40px" height="40px">&#9823;</td>
                <td class="black" width="40px" height="40px">&#9823;</td>
                <td width="40px" height="40px">&#9823;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="40px" height="40px"></td>
                <td class="black" width="40px" height="40px"></td>
                <td width="40px" height="40px"></td>
                <td class="black" width="40px" height="40px"></td>
                <td width="40px" height="40px"></td>
                <td class="black" width="40px" height="40px"></td>
                <td width="40px" height="40px"></td>
                <td class="black" width="40px" height="40px"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="black" width="40px" height="40px"></td>
                <td width="40px" height="40px"></td>
                <td class="black" width="40px" height="40px"></td>
                <td width="40px" height="40px"></td>
                <td class="black" width="40px" height="40px"></td>
                <td width="40px" height="40px"></td>
                <td class="black" width="40px" height="40px"></td>
                <td width="40px" height="40px"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="40px" height="40px"></td>
                <td class="black" width="40px" height="40px"></td>
                <td width="40px" height="40px"></td>
                <td class="black" width="40px" height="40px"></td>
                <td width="40px" height="40px"></td>
                <td class="black" width="40px" height="40px"></td>
                <td width="40px" height="40px"></td>
                <td class="black" width="40px" height="40px"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="black" width="40px" height="40px"></td>
                <td width="40px" height="40px"></td>
                <td class="black" width="40px" height="40px"></td>
                <td width="40px" height="40px"></td>
                <td class="black" width="40px" height="40px"></td>
                <td width="40px" height="40px"></td>
                <td class="black" width="40px" height="40px"></td>
                <td width="40px" height="40px"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="40px" height="40px">&#9817;</td>
                <td class="black" width="40px" height="40px">&#9817;</td>
                <td width="40px" height="40px">&#9817;</td>
                <td class="black" width="40px" height="40px">&#9817;</td>
                <td width="40px" height="40px">&#9817;</td>
                <td class="black" width="40px" height="40px">&#9817;</td>
                <td width="40px" height="40px">&#9817;</td>
                <td class="black" width="40px" height="40px">&#9817;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="black" width="40px" height="40px">&#9814;</td>
                <td width="40px" height="40px">&#9816;</td>
                <td class="black" width="40px" height="40px">&#9815;</td>
                <td width="40px" height="40px">&#9813;</td>
                <td class="black" width="40px" height="40px">&#9812;</td>
                <td width="40px" height="40px">&#9815;</td>
                <td class="black" width="40px" height="40px">&#9816;</td>
                <td width="40px" height="40px">&#9814;</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
```

`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check jQueryUI's

Draggable: http://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Droppable: http://jqueryui.com/droppable/

with these two, you can create a chess like game using only javascript